# Removing rows with identical first column value in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a cell matrix of size 10000 X 3 in Matlab and I would like to remove rows with the same value in the first column.

That is, if row i and row j have the same value in the first column, I'd like to delete both rows.

I should also say that there can be more than two rows with the same value in the first column and in that case, I'd like to delete all these rows.

How do I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the functions [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/histc.html), [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/unique.html) and logical indexing to achieve what you want. Here's a small example.

```
a=randi(10,5,3)         %#generate a sample random matrix

a =

     5     3     5
     5     7    10
     7     7     4
     8     2     6
     8     2     3

[uniqVals,uniqIndx]=unique(a(:,1));  %# get unique values and corresponding indices of the first column of a
count=histc(a(:,1),uniqVals); %# get the bin counts of the elements (i.e., find which are repeated)

b=a(uniqIndx(count==1),:)

b =

     7     7     4
```

Only the row with the non-repeated element is selected. Since you said that you have a cell matrix, simply covert it to a matrix using [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cell2mat.html) before doing this.

Comment: are they all strings or are they mixed?